# Remove xml version tage from String

Tags: java, regex

How to remove `<xml version>` tag from XML String in Java.

I tried the following but this doesn't help.

```
XmlString = XmlString.replaceAll("<?xml*?>", "").trim();
```

I also tried

```
XmlString = XmlString.replaceAll("\\<\\?xml(.+?)\\?\\>", "").trim();
```

Comment: tried following too:XmlString=XmlString.replaceAll("<?xml*?>", "").trim();

Comment: XmlString=XmlString.replaceAll("\\<\\?xml(.+?)\\?\\>", "").trim();

Comment: The `<` and `>` signs are not special in regular expressions so there is no need to put backslashes before them.

Answer (score 2):

For your regex **`<?xml*?>`**:

1. You must escape **?** because it is a meta character.

So, the regex should be modified as **`<\\?xml*\\?>`** at first step.

2. The meta character that means any character (as wild card) is not  ***** (an asterisk) but **.** (a dot) in regex.
3. ***** works as quantifier for adjacent character means zero or more.

So, you should use **.*** right after **xml**:  **`<\\?xml.*\\?>`**

4. ***** gulps as long as possible. To make it as short as possible, you are better using ***?** than *****.

So the final regex comes **`<\\?xml.*?\\?>`**.

Below is a working sample code:

```
String xmlString = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>";
System.out.println(xmlString);
xmlString = xmlString.replaceAll("<\\?xml.*?\\?>", "");
System.out.println(xmlString);
```

Comment: @Jamen, ok, I updated my answer although I thought the questioner was just seeking the right regex and that (just indicating a working example) was enough.

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions are complex.  There's no need to introduce that complexity for what you're trying to do.  Try this instead:

```
xmlString = xmlString.substring(xmlString.indexOf("?>") + 2);
```